# Hard drive is corrupted. Trying to fix it with a PC

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, partition

Test disk managed to fix the partition type but I'm still getting these errors.
How can I fix this?
I'm not sure if it's bootable yet I have to go to my friend's place for the machine.

[image: Error in testdisk]

Comment: If this is a mac formatted drive then I would not expect a pc to be able to fix it - I have used macs to repair pc formatted drives though... trying to use a pc to fix a mac format drive may be the best way to loose all the data...

Comment: Those error messages are because the HD being analyzed does not have any FAT partitions (check_FAT). Meaningless in your situation.